# Is there any better way to store the user's password which works for both stock and rooted device?

Tags: android, cryptography, sqlcipher

Let me explain my constraints,

- I would like have encrypted database using [sqlcipher](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/),
- I would like get the encryption key for sqlcipher from users and don't want to prompt for password (encryption key for sqlcipher) every time user launches the application, rather i would like to store it in a secured way.

I found a blog post on way to store the password in keystore by [**nelenkov**](http://nelenkov.blogspot.in/2012/05/storing-application-secrets-in-androids.html), as quoted in the blog post such methods can subject to brute-force attack in rooted devices.

> Is there any other better way to store the user's password which works
>   for both normal and rooted device?
>
> Can we combine google/google+ or any other single signon solution for
>   this purpose?

Kindly share your thoughts.